# Detect "Application has stopped working" and restart exe

Tags: c#, wcf, nunit

I am writing nunit tests to test my application which uses wcf communication internally.
When a test is running and an unhandled exception occurs, the exe hosting wcf service crashes with a dialog "... has stopped working". After this no tests are executed and waits for me to close the programm, so that next test starts the process again.
Is there a way to detect this wcf host exe crash and kill the process, so that the next tests can continue? (a separate console application monitoring the wcf host exe).
I tried to use property Process.Responding to check status, but is not working.

Comment: handle unhandle exception look at this http://www.csharp-examples.net/catching-unhandled-exceptions/

Comment: I have found that there are different processes that can display this dialog. Two processes I found were ```WerFault``` and ```DWWIN```. But there is at least one additional dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Just check if an app is running but its id

```
bool exist = Process.GetProcesses().Any(x => x.Id == id);
```

You can get an process id by

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
p.Start();
int id = p.Id;
```

For current app

```
int id = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
```

Comment: The exe is still running when exception dialog is displayed.